# Is there a way to directly send an OpenCV frame using telepot?

Tags: opencv, telepot

I am doing an OpenCV project and I cant seem to find a way to send the frames using telepot module to my telegram. I've already setup the telegram bot.

```
------------Opencv processing------
cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
bot.sendPhoto(238460030, (frame,'rb'))
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken you need to **take the photo first** ,then you need to send the file with:

`photo = ("img.jpeg",mode= 'rb')`